# vars.c:4:1: error: expected declaration specifiers or '...' before '(' token

Tags: c, windows, declaration

I am 13 and learning c programming and so I have an incredibly basic understanding of c programming. I'm learning how to 'Display Variable Values',I'm using VERY basic code but when i try to compile it using GNU (MinGW) it tells me...

vars.c:4:1: error: expected declaration specifiers or '...' before '(' token

Please may someone tell me how i could fix this!

This is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h> 

int main(
(printf( "Integer is %d \n",num);
(printf( "Values are %d and %f \n",num,pi);
(printf( "%%7d displays %7d \n",num);
(printf( "%%07d displays %07d \n",num);
(printf( "Pi is approximately %1.10f \n",pi);
(printf( "Right-aligned %20.3f rounded pi \n",pi);
(printf( "Left-aligned %-20.3f rounded pi \n",pi);
return 0 ;)
)
({
int num = 100;
double pi = 3.1415926536;
(return 0 ;)
})
```

Comment: Did you write this code or is this code given as a problem to you?

Comment: Have you learned Lisp or Scheme before? You're using way too many parentheses, a lot of them invalid.

Comment: Here is some tutorial to introduce you to the [C programming](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/c-tutorial.html). Enjoy!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure where you came up with this code, but I'm assuming you intended to type the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
        int num = 100;
        double pi = 3.1415926536;

        printf( "Integer is %d \n",num);
        printf( "Values are %d and %f \n",num,pi);
        printf( "%%7d displays %7d \n",num);
        printf( "%%07d displays %07d \n",num);
        printf( "Pi is approximately %1.10f \n",pi);
        printf( "Right-aligned %20.3f rounded pi \n",pi);
        printf( "Left-aligned %-20.3f rounded pi \n",pi);

        return 0 ;
}
```

Try to find an online C programming tutorial and work your way through it. It will prove to be much more satisfactory than trial and error.

Answer (score 2):

The syntax you are using is pretty much entirely wrong starting on the third line.  You never finished declaring the arguments of `main` and you have tons of extra parentheses.  You should Google for "c hello world" and try to run those examples so you can get a feel for what C code looks like.  Here is an example that might help:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int num = 100;
    printf("Hello World\n");
    printf("Integer is %d\n",num);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you I think I'm getting in ahead of myself! May have to read up a bit!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

At least three problems:

1) completely unnecessary parenthesis

2) Uninitialized variables

3) ???Trying to create a lambda in your main()???

Suggested modifications:

```
#include <stdio.h> 

int main() {
  int num = 100;
  double pi = 3.1415926536;

  printf( "Integer is %d \n",num);
  printf( "Values are %d and %f \n",num,pi);
  return 0 ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Working version of your code:

```
#include <stdio.h> 

int main() {
  int num = 100;
  float pi = 3.1415926536;

  printf( "Integer is %d \n",num);
  printf( "Values are %d and %f \n",num,pi);
  printf( "%%7d displays %7d \n",num);
  printf( "%%07d displays %07d \n",num);
  printf( "Pi is approximately %1.10f \n",pi);
  printf( "Right-aligned %20.3f rounded pi \n",pi);
  printf( "Left-aligned %-20.3f rounded pi \n",pi);

  return 0;
}
```